# Is it ghost layer or what is it?

Tags: modeling

Hello team and everyone,
I dunno how but some objects in outliner dupped and generated automatically (or maybe I accidentally clicked a shortcut key IDK).
Now, whenever I try to delete the dupped objects in outliner, original objects are also deleted, I even can not move them.

Please help me to get rid from this problem.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior. The objects are showing up twice because they are parented to an object that is not in the same collection as them. They appear primarily in their collection, secondarily as children of the parent object. To make this duplicate appearance not happen, either place them in the same collection as their parent object, or vice versa.

Comment: When I place parent objects in duplicate collection and try to delete duplicate objects the parent objects also gt deleted.

Comment: @SGPainting3D You misunderstood. Each “duplicate” is actually only one object, it’s just showing up twice in the outliner. Don’t try to delete it.

Comment: Ohhhh I see, thank you so much for the explanation.